# spring boot pom.xml Failure to transfer

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, pom.xml

I've just create a new spring boot projet and i have a probleme in the pom.xml and i have no idea how to resolve it, please some help, thanks for all.

the error in the the pom.xml it in the parent tag whitch is :

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:ProjetTest:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer 
 org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.0.RELEASE from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local 
 repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not 
 transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.0.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/
 maven2): Connection refused: connect and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Ticketing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Ticketing</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: please share the beginning `<project>` tag

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Things to try

1. You can try replacing your beginning `<project>` tag like below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Other stuff of the pom.xml here -->
</project>
```

2. You need to remove `<relativePath/>` and the parent will look like below:-

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <!-- use your specific version here -->
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

3. If still it is not resolving then it could be various things like:-

   1. internet connection, could be proxy issue also
   2. try deleting the folder `M2_FOLDER_LOCATION\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-parent` and then re importing the project.

Answer (score 12):

I was facing the same problem.
I followed the following steps:

1. Right-click on the project and select Maven,
2. Click on Update Project,
3. Except Offline select every checkbox.

It should work fine now.

Comment: Solved my problem, Thanks

Comment: goo boy very goo boy

Answer (score 2):

`relativePath` requires a path inside it like so:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

All you likely need to do is remove `<relativePath/>` and make your parent look like so:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a internet proxy issue.

This might be a problem with the internet proxy as well. Check your internet proxy settings. Somehow MAVEN is not able to download the dependencies because of proxy.

If you are using proxy, then follow steps mentioned in below link
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

I have used below configuration to make it work.

```
<settings>
<proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <!--
      <username>....</username>
      <password>....</password>
      -->
      <host>proxy.abcd.com</host>
      <port>1234</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
   </proxies>
</settings>
```

Comment: for everyone who have the same issue with proxy. put this part in the maven settings.xml file. you will find it under C:\Users\user name\.m2 if you did not find it i created it using intellij. open pom.xml and right click => maven => create settings.xml. und after that you will find the file in  C:\Users\user name\.m2

Answer (score 0):

I was practicing in home, so no proxy with one ISP, it was causing a problem but it was not before in any project for practice only. So deleted the setting.xml in .m2 folder (in windows os). parent error in pom.xml disappeared